# Sentiment Analysis negation handling and selecting sentiment score

Tags: compiler-construction, machine-learning, nlp, feature-selection

I have a Hindi parser which outputs parse tree of sentence and my objective is to find the scope of negation words (not, never) so that I can reverse the polarity.

- How to use it to find the scope or do I need to convert it into dependency graph.
- How to convert parse tree into dependency graph and is the algorithm depends on language(Hindi,English)
- Also I am using sentiwordnet and there are words which have both positive and negative score so which one should I choose as feature vector.
- I am using part of speech tags for word sense disambiguation so how to use that information.
  I'll be using SVM to train as classifier